# tastypie no limit as default behavior

Tags: django, tastypie

There's a possibility to append `?limit=0` phrase at the end of the API URL to make the query not limit the response. Is there any way to mae it a default behavior, e.g. http://my.api.com/resources/ (without ?limit=0) will return all resources?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As [the documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html) shows, you can use the `limit` variable in the resource's `Meta` class:

```
class FooResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        limit = 0
```

Or you can set it for all models with the global settings variable `API_LIMIT_PER_PAGE`.

Comment: Thi is strange, because setting `API_LIMIT_PER_PAGE = 0` results in limit set to `1000`. So I guess there's an unbreakable limit not to make django process suffocate. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: That is odd! Does the same happen if you set limit to 0 on the resource individually?

Comment: It's capped by `max_limit`; see [Jonya Murabe's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18477897/17498).

Comment: found jonya's answer to work.  i did not try without max_limit

Answer (score 14):

```
class FooResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        limit = 0
        max_limit = 0
```